# Java, can't read from file

Tags: java

When ever I enter a name the file is created and the lines are there but when I use the display method, it spits out that error and I am not sure where my problem is and I'm kinda new to Java. I have a method in another class to save the lines but I don't think that is where my problem is, and I am kinda stuck, any help would be appreciated.

```
    package X;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class FileDisplay {
        String filename;

        public FileDisplay(String name) {name = filename;}

        public void display() throws IOException {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                String str = inputFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            inputFile.close();
        }


    }
```

I ran the code and every time it spits out this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:276)
    at ES1036a.Lab6.FileDisplay.display(FileDisplay.java:12)
    at ES1036a.Lab6.FilesDemo.main(FilesDemo.java:27)
```

And this is the demo class :

```
    package X;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;
    public class FilesDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String filename = "lines.txt";

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What's the filename?");

            filename = keyboard.nextLine();

            FileSave FilesDemo = new FileSave(filename);
            FilesDemo.save("1-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n" +
                    "2-Consectetuer adipiscing elit\n" +
                    "3-Sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt\n" +
                    "4-Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam\n" +
                    "5-Quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper\n" +
                    "6-Suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat\n" +
                    "7-Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit\n" +
                    "8-Vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros");


            FileDisplay FilesDemo2 = new FileDisplay(filename);

            FilesDemo2.display();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `name = filename;` does?

Comment: It would take the value that I put in constructor from the democlass

Comment: Is that value stored in `name` or in `filename`?

Comment: Please consider deleting your question, this was essentially due to a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In constructor of FileDisplay you left the attribute named "filenamed" unassigned, correct it in this way:

```
public FileDisplay(String name) {
    /*  wrong
    the parameter String "name" is reassigned but you need
    to assing the class attribute "filneame", this line is wrong:
    name = filename;
    */

    // correct 
    filename = name;
}
```

Comment: This is the 3rd such question today about an assignment done in the wrong direction. Since they're doing it correctly elsewhere, we can assume this was a "typo". Please don't get into the habit of answering such questions. Instead flag them with the close reason you can see above, and maybe drop a comment. We don't want to keep these questions around and an answer makes it harder to delete.